# (React Native Gesture Handler) Tried to synchronously call function from a different thread

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-native-gesture-handler

I am trying to change state from a pan gesture (React Native Gesture Handler).

```
const [localShowRecents, setLocalShowRecents] = useState(false)
const translateY = useSharedValue(0);

const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
      .onStart(() => {
        context.value = { y: translateY.value }
      })
      .onUpdate((event) => {
        //console.log(event.translationY);
        translateY.value = event.translationY + context.value.y;
        translateY.value = Math.max(translateY.value, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y)
      })
      .onEnd(() => {
      if (translateY.value > -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 32){
        setLocalShowRecents(true); //change state
      }
}
```

When I try to update state from the ".onEnd()" function, I get the error "Tried to synchronously call function from a different thread." How do I properly change state from the gesture handler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Reanimated components work on the device's UI thread. The rest of your code will work on the device's JS thread. The way your code is written, it tries to call a Javascript function on the UI thread, which causes the error you're seeing.

This is why Reanimated includes the `runOnJS` method.  Instead of

```js
  setLocalShowRecents(true)
```

you can use

```js
  runOnJS(setLocalShowRecents)(true);
```

Note the modified call signature - `runOnJS(fn)(args)`.  You can read more about runOnJS [here in the Reanimated docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/miscellaneous/runOnJS/).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: npx react-native start --reset-cache, https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/discussions/1571#discussioncomment-3108509